# SQLite3: non-ascii characters not updated correctly?

Tags: c, sqlite

I'm trying to update a specific text column(WVARCHAR) on sqlite row using `sqlite3_bind_text16()` on my C program but unfortunately, only the strings that contains only ascii encoded characters like `L"e"` are updated correctly, but the other strings containing unicode characters like `L"é"`are updated having the non-ascii characters not stored correctly. here is example how I used the function:

```
sqlite3_bind_text16(stmt, 1, L"e", -1, SQLITE_STATIC); //e is stored correctly
sqlite3_bind_text16(stmt, 2, L"é", -1, SQLITE_STATIC); //é not stored correctly: modified
```

I tested that by doing select command using sqlite shell for my program's sqlite database file.

so how to fix that?

Comment: What happens to the non-ASCII characters?

Comment: http://picsee.net/upload/2014-05-14/42d9402a739d.png

Comment: The Windows command shell does not handle SQLite's UTF-8 characters correctly. Use any other program to show the database contents, or show the output of `SELECT hex(MyColumn) FROM taxdeclarations;`.

Comment: so you want to say, that there is nothing wrong from the side of my C program?

Comment: If you used only the Windows command shell, this might be the case.

Comment: The Microsoft compiler has [a bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/431244/std-ostream-fails-to-write-utf-8-encoded-string-to-console) that [breaks UTF-8 I/O](http://alfps.wordpress.com/2011/11/22/unicode-part-1-windows-console-io-approaches/); the [workaround](http://alfps.wordpress.com/2011/12/08/unicode-part-2-utf-8-stream-mode/#utf8_mode_narrow_fail_fixed) is ugly and nonportable.

Answer (score 0):

Issue the following `PRAGMA` to the database prior to updating:

`PRAGMA encoding = 'utf8';`

This should ensure sqlite is updating non-ASCII characters correctly.

Comment: It is not possible to change the database encoding after the database has been created, and this encoding setting does not change the encoding of strings used in the API.