# SQLite3: non-ascii unicode chars' update not working?

Tags: c, sqlite

I'm using SQLite3 under win32, I'm always getting the non-ascii characters transformated into dangling ones when updating a WVARCHAR column using SQLite3 on my C program, here is an example of my code that unfortunately doesn't update correctly the non-ascii chars like 'é':

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sqlite3.h>

    int main(){
      sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
      sqlite3 *sqdb;

      sqlite3_initialize();
      sqlite3_open("sqlite_unicode_test", &sqdb);
       const char* table_check = {
      "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable("
       "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
       "mycolumn1 WVARCHAR,"
       "mycolumn2 WVARCHAR"
       ");"
       };
      sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqdb, table_check, -1, &stmt, 0);
      sqlite3_step(stmt);
      sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
      sqlite3_prepare16(sqdb, L"UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn1=? mycolumn2=? WHERE(id=0)", -1, &stmt, 0);
      sqlite3_bind_text16(stmt, 1, L"e", -1, SQLITE_STATIC); //e is stored correctly on the database
      sqlite3_bind_text16(stmt, 2, L"é", -1, SQLITE_STATIC); //however é not stored correctly: modified by a dangled character
      sqlite3_step(stmt);
      sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
      sqlite3_close(sqdb);
    }
```

I don't know why this is happening, I posted before a question about that
 ([SQLite3: non-ascii characters not updated correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23663121/sqlite3-non-ascii-characters-not-updated-correctly)) but I don't think this is related to sqlite3 win32 binaries because I tested
 building SQLite by myself using gcc and there is always the same problem.
so what's wrong with the SQLite unicode? and how can I exactly solve the problem? I need help.

Comment: +1 for reducing this to a simple case

Comment: can you show your connection statement...

Comment: @ojblass what do you mean by 'can you show your connection statement'? do you mean a screenshot from the shell?

Comment: obviously before you prepare a statment you have to open a db connection with some options...

Comment: @ojblass I updated above the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two things you must do :

When you create the database you must specify utf-16 (I think UTF-8 is the default).

In addition when before you bind the character you must convert the accented character to UTF-16 and not pass a UNICODE string.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276215/make-sure-the-sqlite-on-android-uses-utf-8-as-a-charset)  and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421785/how-can-i-use-unicode-characters-such-as-germanic-umlaut-in-an-sqlite-database) for more information.

Comment: thanks a lot, that really helped me to solve the problem! thanks again.